# Understanding cats effect `Cancelable `

Tags: scala-cats, cats-effect

I am trying to understand how cats effect `Cancelable` works. I have the following minimal app, based on the [documentation](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/io.html#cancelable-processeshttps://)

```scala
import java.util.concurrent.{Executors, ScheduledExecutorService}
import cats.effect._
import cats.implicits._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Main extends IOApp {
  def delayedTick(d: FiniteDuration)
                 (implicit sc: ScheduledExecutorService): IO[Unit] = {

    IO.cancelable { cb =>
      val r = new Runnable {
        def run() =
          cb(Right(()))
      }
      val f = sc.schedule(r, d.length, d.unit)

      // Returning the cancellation token needed to cancel
      // the scheduling and release resources early
      val mayInterruptIfRunning = false
      IO(f.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning)).void
    }
  }

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    val scheduledExecutorService =
      Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
    for {
      x <- delayedTick(1.second)(scheduledExecutorService)
      _ <- IO(println(s"$x"))
    } yield ExitCode.Success
  }
}
```

When I run this:

```
❯ sbt run
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/ethan/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading settings for project stackoverflow-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/ethan/IdeaProjects/stackoverflow/project
[info] Loading settings for project stackoverflow from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to cats-effect-tutorial (in build file:/Users/ethan/IdeaProjects/stackoverflow/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/ethan/IdeaProjects/stackoverflow/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[info] running (fork) Main
[info] ()
```

The program just hangs at this point. I have many questions:

1. Why does the program hang instead of terminating after 1 second?
2. Why do we set `mayInterruptIfRunning = false`? Isn't the whole point of cancellation to interrupt a running task?
3. Is this the recommended way to define the `ScheduledExecutorService`? I did not see examples in the docs.
4. This program waits 1 second, and then returns `()` (then unexpectedly hangs). What if I wanted to return something else? For example, let's say I wanted to return a string, the result of some long-running computation. How would I extract that value from `IO.cancelable`? The difficulty, it seems, is that `IO.cancelable` returns the cancelation operation, not the return value of the process to be cancelled.

Pardon the long post but this is my `build.sbt`:

```
name := "cats-effect-tutorial"

version := "1.0"

fork := true

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % "1.3.0" withSources() withJavadoc()

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-feature",
  "-deprecation",
  "-unchecked",
  "-language:postfixOps",
  "-language:higherKinds",
  "-Ypartial-unification")
```

Answer (score 1):

you need shutdown the `ScheduledExecutorService`, Try this

```
Resource.make(IO(Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor))(se => IO(se.shutdown())).use {
      se =>
        for {
          x <- delayedTick(5.second)(se)
          _ <- IO(println(s"$x"))
        } yield ExitCode.Success
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer to these questions although there are still some things that I don't understand.

> Why does the program hang instead of terminating after 1 second?

For some reason, `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` causes things to hang. To fix the problem, I had to use `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new Thread(_))`. It appears that the only difference is that the first version is equivalent to `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(Executors.defaultThreadFactory())`, although nothing in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) makes it clear why this is the case.

> Why do we set `mayInterruptIfRunning = false`? Isn't the whole point of cancellation to interrupt a running task?

I have to admit that I do not understand this entirely. Again, [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) were not especially clarifying on this point. Switching the flag to `true` does not seem to change the behavior at all, at least in the case of `Ctrl-c` interrupts.

> Is this the recommended way to define the ScheduledExecutorService? I did not see examples in the docs.

Clearly not. The way that I came up with was loosely inspired by [this snippet](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/ab68a888aaa1a8552dd7cbbe6695010924201eae/core/jvm/src/main/scala/cats/effect/internals/IOTimer.scala#L83) from the cats effect source code.

> This program waits 1 second, and then returns `()` (then unexpectedly hangs). What if I wanted to return something else? For example, let's say I wanted to return a string, the result of some long-running computation. How would I extract that value from `IO.cancelable`? The difficulty, it seems, is that `IO.cancelable` returns the cancelation operation, not the return value of the process to be cancelled.

The `IO.cancellable { ... }` block returns `IO[A]` and the callback `cb` function has type `Either[Throwable, A] => Unit`. Logically this suggests that whatever is fed into the `cb` function is what the IO.cancellable expression will returned (wrapped in `IO`). So to return the string `"hello"` instead of `()`, we rewrite `delayedTick`:

```scala
  def delayedTick(d: FiniteDuration)
                 (implicit sc: ScheduledExecutorService): IO[String] = { // Note IO[String] instead of IO[Unit]

    implicit val processRunner: JVMProcessRunner[IO] = new JVMProcessRunner
    IO.cancelable[String] { cb => // Note IO.cancelable[String] instead of IO[Unit]
      val r = new Runnable {
        def run() =
          cb(Right("hello")) // Note "hello" instead of ()
      }
      val f: ScheduledFuture[_] = sc.schedule(r, d.length, d.unit)
      IO(f.cancel(true))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need explicitly `terminate` the executor at the end, as it is not managed by Scala or Cats runtime, it wouldn't exit by itself, that's why your App hands up instead of exit immediately.
2. `mayInterruptIfRunning = false` gracefully terminates a thread if it is running. You can set it as `true` to forcely kill it, but it is not recommanded.
3. You have many way to create a `ScheduledExecutorService`, it depends on need. For this case it doesn't matter, but the question 1.
4. You can return anything from the Cancelable IO by call `cb(Right("put your stuff here"))`, the only thing blocks you to retrieve the return `A` is when your cancellation works. You wouldn't get anything if you stop it before it gets to the point. Try to return `IO(f.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning)).delayBy(FiniteDuration(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).void`, you will get what you expected. Because `2 seconds > 1 second`, your code gets enough time to run before it has been cancelled.